# How to delete working copy from Source Control Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, workspace

I've created working copy in my workspace and now have to delete one. How to delete it from Source Control Xcode? Any help appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the one you want to delete, click `Configure (name)`. Then tab over to remotes, and remove the remote with the minus button.

Comment: I have the same issue. Removed the remote, but the working copy still shows up